# How to query by text string which contains html tags using React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

### Current Working Solution

Using this html:

```html
<p data-testid="foo">Name: <strong>Bob</strong> <em>(special guest)</em></p>
```

I can use the [React Testing Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library) `getByTestId` method to find the `textContent`:

```
expect(getByTestId('foo').textContent).toEqual('Name: Bob (special guest)')
```

### Is there a better way?

I would like to simply use this html:

```html
<p>Name: <strong>Bob</strong> <em>(special guest)</em></p>
```

And use [React Testing Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library)'s `getByText` method like this:

```
expect(getByText('Name: Bob (special guest)')).toBeTruthy()
```

But this does not work.

### So, the question…

Is there a simpler way to use React Testing Library to find strings of text content with the tags striped out?

Comment: This even work if the p has property simply as id as can be for FormHelperText MUI

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Update 2

Having used this many times, I've created a helper. Below is an example test using this helper.

### Test helper:

```
// withMarkup.ts
import { MatcherFunction } from '@testing-library/react'

type Query = (f: MatcherFunction) => HTMLElement

const withMarkup = (query: Query) => (text: string): HTMLElement =>
  query((content: string, node: HTMLElement) => {
    const hasText = (node: HTMLElement) => node.textContent === text
    const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(
      child => !hasText(child as HTMLElement)
    )
    return hasText(node) && childrenDontHaveText
  })

export default withMarkup
```

### Test:

```
// app.test.tsx
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import App from './App'
import withMarkup from '../test/helpers/withMarkup'

it('tests foo and bar', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />)
  const getByTextWithMarkup = withMarkup(getByText)
  getByTextWithMarkup('Name: Bob (special guest)')
})
```

---

## Update 1

Here is an example where a new matcher `getByTextWithMarkup` is created. Note that this function extends `getByText` in a test, thus it must be defined there. (Sure the function could be updated to accept `getByText` as a parameter.)

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";

test("pass functions to matchers", () => {
  const Hello = () => (
    <div>
      Hello <span>world</span>
    </div>
  );
  const { getByText } = render(<Hello />);

  const getByTextWithMarkup = (text: string) => {
    getByText((content, node) => {
      const hasText = (node: HTMLElement) => node.textContent === text
      const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(
        child => !hasText(child as HTMLElement)
      )
      return hasText(node) && childrenDontHaveText
    })
  }

  getByTextWithMarkup('Hello world')
})
```

---

Here is a solid answer from the 4th of [Five Things You (Probably) Didn't Know About Testing Library](https://www.polvara.me/posts/five-things-you-didnt-know-about-testing-library/) from [Giorgio Polvara's Blog](https://www.polvara.me/):

---

## Queries accept functions too

You have probably seen an error like this one:

> Unable to find an element with the text: Hello world.
> This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements.
> In this case, you can provide a function for your text
> matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Usually, it happens because your HTML looks like this:

```html
<div>Hello <span>world</span></div>
```

The solution is contained inside the error message: "[...] you can provide a function for your text matcher [...]".

What's that all about? It turns out matchers accept strings, regular expressions or functions.

The function gets called for each node you're rendering. It receives two arguments: the node's content and the node itself. All you have to do is to return true or false depending on if the node is the one you want.

An example will clarify it:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";

test("pass functions to matchers", () => {
  const Hello = () => (
    <div>
      Hello <span>world</span>
    </div>
  );
  const { getByText } = render(<Hello />);

  // These won't match
  // getByText("Hello world");
  // getByText(/Hello world/);

  getByText((content, node) => {
    const hasText = node => node.textContent === "Hello world";
    const nodeHasText = hasText(node);
    const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(
      child => !hasText(child)
    );

    return nodeHasText && childrenDontHaveText;
  });
});
```

We're ignoring the `content` argument because in this case, it will either be "Hello", "world" or an empty string.

What we are checking instead is that the current node has the right [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). `hasText` is a little helper function to do that. I declared it to keep things clean.

That's not all though. Our `div` is not the only node with the text we're looking for. For example, `body` in this case has the same text. To avoid returning more nodes than needed we are making sure that none of the children has the same text as its parent. In this way we're making sure that the node we're returning is the smallest—in other words the one closes to the bottom of our DOM tree.

---

Read the rest of [Five Things You (Probably) Didn't Know About Testing Library](https://www.polvara.me/posts/five-things-you-didnt-know-about-testing-library/)

Comment: I'm not understanding why this is necessary since, as per the [testing-library docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytext), `getByText` looks for the textContent already, and hence `getByText("Hello World")` should work, right (although it seems not to for some reason)?

Comment: That's because `getByText` is using the [`getNodeText`](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/master/src/get-node-text.js) helper which is looking for the `textContent` property of each *text node*. In your case, the only text nodes that are direct children of `<p>` are `Name: ` and ` `. I'm not sure why RTL decides not to look for text nodes that are children of children in a recursive way. Maybe it's for performance reasons but that's the way it is. Maybe @kentcdodds can provide some more insights on this

Comment: Thinking about it RTL doesn't look for children of children because otherwise this getAllByText(`<div><div>Hello</div></div>`, 'Hello') would return two results. It makes sense

Comment: Nice answer. I also had to catch the exception thrown by `getByText` and re-throw another message with `text`, because it's not included in the error message when using a custom matcher. I think it would be great to have this helper included by default on  `@testing-library`.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti -  Can you please post the solution you describe as another answer to this question?

Comment: With simplified internal types:

`const withMarkup = (query: Query) => (text: string) => {
  const hasText = (node: Element) => node.textContent === text;

  return query((_, node) => {
    const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(child => !hasText(child));
    return hasText(node) && childrenDontHaveText;
  });
};`

Comment: Latest update gives compiler warnings. `node: HTMLElement` Should be `node: Element | null`. All other `HTMLElement`s should be `Element`. `Array.from(node.children)`: Warning *node can be null`.

Comment: Can anyone provide an example how to make this helper function work with all `BoundFunctions` from  the Testing Library, like `getAllByText`, please?

Answer (score 61):

For substring matching, you can pass `{ exact: false }`:

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#textmatch

```js
const el = getByText('Name:', { exact: false })
expect(el.textContent).toEqual('Name: Bob (special guest)');
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution.  In this case something like: expect(getByText('Name:', { exact: false }).textContent).toEqual('Name: Bob (special guest)');

Comment: Great solution that doesn't involve `testId` matchers!

Answer (score 43):

If you are using `testing-library/jest-dom` in your project. You can also use `toHaveTextContent`.

```js
expect(getByTestId('foo')).toHaveTextContent('Name: Bob (special guest)')
```

if you need a partial match, you can also use regex search patterns

```
expect(getByTestId('foo')).toHaveTextContent(/Name: Bob/)
```

Here's a link to the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/jest-dom#tohavetextcontent)

Comment: This is an assertion though, you first need something else to find the element. OP is looking for a query to find the element

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60865407/2333214) could be adapted with this assertion like `const el = getByText('Name:', { exact: false });
expect(el).toHaveTextContent('Name: Bob (special guest)');`

Comment: That's right. I hadn't realized that the OP was looking for a way to query an element by the text content.

Answer (score 15):

The existing answers are outdated. The new [*ByRole](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole) query supports this:

```
getByRole('button', {name: 'Bob (special guest)'})
```

Comment: How would that work in this case, where there is no 'button'?

Comment: @jarthur - Use the accessibility DOM to inspect the element you're targeting to determine its role.

Comment: I'm wondering in OP's context, there is no obvious role. Unless `p` has a default role?

Comment: @jarthur - <p> has a role of paragraph. However, oddly getByRole ignores paragraphs. So you need to use a different wrapper element that getByRole currently supports like a heading or a region.

Comment: @CoryHouse - how about if there are no element with accessible role and only elements like this:

<div><b>[AL]</b> Albania</div>
<div><b>[DZ]</b> Algeria</div>

How can I query the first element by its text?

Comment: @dariusz - I'd suggest improving your markup so that it's more semantic. Then testing is easier, and likely accessibility will be better too.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

The solution below works but for some cases, it might return more than one result. This is the correct implementation:

```
getByText((_, node) => {
  const hasText = node => node.textContent === "Name: Bob (special guest)";
  const nodeHasText = hasText(node);
  const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(
    child => !hasText(child)
  );

  return nodeHasText && childrenDontHaveText;
});
```

---

You can pass a method to `getbyText`:

```js
getByText((_, node) => node.textContent === 'Name: Bob (special guest)')
```

You could put the code into a helper function so you don't have to type it all the time:

```js
  const { getByText } = render(<App />)
  const getByTextWithMarkup = (text) =>
    getByText((_, node) => node.textContent === text)
```

Comment: This solution can work in simple scenarios, however if it produced the error "Found multiple elements with the text: (_, node) => node.textContent === 'Name: Bob (special guest)'", then try the other answer's solution which checks child nodes as well.

Comment: Agree, the solution is actually taken from my blog :D

Comment: Thanks for your insight with this Giorgio. I keep coming back to these answers as I find I need these solutions in new tests. :)

Comment: Is there a way to modify this idea to work with cypress-testing-library?

Comment: Compiler warning: `[node] Object is possibly null` at `Array.from(node.children`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid matching multiple elements, for *some* use cases simply only returning elements that actually have text content themselves, filters out unwanted parents just fine:

```js
expect(
  // - content: text content of current element, without text of its children
  // - element.textContent: content of current element plus its children
  screen.getByText((content, element) => {
    return content !== '' && element.textContent === 'Name: Bob (special guest)';
  })
).toBeInTheDocument();
```

The above requires *some* content for the element one is testing, so works for:

```html
<div>
  <p>Name: <strong>Bob</strong> <em>(special guest)</em></p>
</div>
```

...but not if `<p>` has no text content of its own:

```html
<div>
  <p><em>Name: </em><strong>Bob</strong><em> (special guest)</em></p>
</div>
```

So, for a generic solution the other answers are surely better.

Answer (score 1):

```
getByText('Hello World'); // full string match
getByText('llo Worl', { exact: false }); // substring match
getByText('hello world', { exact: false }); // ignore case-sensitivity
```

source: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/#queries

Comment: This does not work for `<div>hello<span> world</span></div>`, which is what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers ended up in type errors or non-functional code at all. This worked for me.

Note: I'm using `screen.*` here

```
import React from 'react';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';

/**
 * Preparation: generic function for markup 
 * matching which allows a customized 
 * /query/ function.
 **/
namespace Helper {
    type Query = (f: MatcherFunction) => HTMLElement

    export const byTextWithMarkup = (query: Query, textWithMarkup: string) => {
        return query((_: string, node: Element | null) => {
            const hasText = (node: Element | null) => !!(node?.textContent === textWithMarkup);
            const childrenDontHaveText = node ? Array.from(node.children).every(
                child => !hasText(child as Element)
            ) : false;
        return hasText(node) && childrenDontHaveText
    })}
}


/**
 * Functions you use in your test code.
 **/
export class Jest {
    static getByTextWithMarkup = (textWithMarkup: string) =>  Helper.byTextWithMarkup(screen.getByText, textWithMarkup);
    static queryByTextWith = (textWithMarkup: string) =>  Helper.byTextWithMarkup(screen.queryByText, textWithMarkup);
}
```

Usage:

```
Jest.getByTextWithMarkup("hello world");
Jest.queryByTextWithMarkup("hello world");
```