# How to access text broken by multiple elements in Testing Library

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, testing-library

here is my code example

```
<div class="dropdown" data-testid="dropdown">
  <div class="option" data-testid="option">
   <b>[AF]</b> Afghanistan
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-testid="option">
   <b>[AL]</b> Albania
  </div>
  <div class="option" data-testid="option">
   <b>[DZ]</b> Algeria
  </div>
 </div>
```

What I need to do is to access the first element by its text to trigger the
userEvent.selectOptions

```
const dropdown = getByTestId('dropdown');
userEvent.selectOptions(dropdown, screen.getByText('[AF] Afghanistan'))
```

What I get is :

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text:
> [AF] Afghanistan. This could be because the text is broken up by
> multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your
> text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

It's obviously because the text I'm trying to query is broken by  elements.

Please note, that this is not a select/option dropdown and it doesn't have any accessible roles so I can only query it by screen.getByText

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query by text string which contains html tags using React Testing Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509875/how-to-query-by-text-string-which-contains-html-tags-using-react-testing-library)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`getBy*` queries accept a [TextMatch](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#textmatch) as an argument, which means the argument can be either a string, a regex, or a function. In this case, we can use a function (rather than a string) and target the specific element we want to select.

Here's a helper function that applies this logic and makes it reusable.

```js
const getByTextContent = (text) => {
    // Passing function to `getByText`
    return screen.getByText((content, element) => {
        const hasText = element => element.textContent === text
        const elementHasText = hasText(element)
        const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(element?.children || []).every(child => !hasText(child))
        return elementHasText && childrenDontHaveText
  })
}
```

To quickly explain what's going on: The query will traverse all elements in the DOM, but we want to avoid returning more elements than needed. We make sure that none of the children has the same text as its parent. This ensures that the element we return is the one that actually contains the target text.

The `getByTextContent` helper function can then be used in your tests as follows.

```js
const dropdown = getByTestId('dropdown');
userEvent.selectOptions(dropdown, getByTextContent('[AF] Afghanistan'))
```

Comment: I'm using this and getting the following error
**TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: (content, node) => { /* istanbul ignore next */ cov_21pldi4...**

Comment: I removed the await method within expect method and it fixed it.